# How to tell the hotplug system which NTFS driver to use?

Tags: ntfs

I need a NTFS-3G version later than the one shipped with lucid lynx because I want to make use of the new hide_hid_files and hide_dot_files mount options, which are not present before version 2010.8.8.

Ever since I compiled and installed the latest version of NTFS-3G via checkinstall, whenever I plugin a NTFS mass storage device, Ubuntu chooses the ntfs kernel module upon the ntfs-3g fuse driver to mount it. I don't know how to tell my system to use the 3g driver.

`mount -t ntfs-3g` and `fstab` entries work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but the NTFS driver module shipped with the Ubuntu kernel is the NTFS 3G, for such a core component I recommended you to keep with the official packaged version.

Comment: Why you recommend doing so?

Comment: Because the official package version was properly tested and is supported by the Ubuntu community. The latest version may not be as stable as the official package one.

Comment: listen. i need a version newer than the one shipped with lucid. i need the hide_hid_files and hide_dot_files mount options and they just were not there before version 2010.8.8. simple as that.

Comment: koloman, please improve your question per your comment, the clear goal is to upgrade the ntfs driver in order to support those features, 3G vs non 3G is misleading

Comment: done. thanks for the hint. i didn't know i could edit questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can blacklist that kernel module by adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist ntfs
```

Comment: good idea! unfortunately it didn't work. obviously udev loads the module despite the fact it's on the blacklist.